# Change background color of buttons from another activity onCheckedChange through shared preference(?)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have 4 buttons in MainActivity that lead to different activities and by default they are set to have image background.

I click a button in main activity and it gets me to Options activity in where I have a switch.
'

```
//creates instance of the button and redirects to appropriate activity/class on button click
        //options
        Button options = findViewById(R.id.options);
        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentOptions = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Options.class);
                startActivity(intentOptions);
            }
        });
```

'

When that switch is checked I want for Options background(for user feedback) to change to a color and so 4 buttons in MainActivity (I don't want to start MainActivity).

However, I obviously get a null object reference error because I try to change smth in another activity.

I read a bunch of similar topics here and I understand that I should use Shared Preference to store smth(what?) that will allow me to change background of the buttons in another activity and then pass it (how?) to Options and pass it back(?) from Options on Switch check(???).

I am a newbie in java and android and I can't grasp how to solve my problem.

Code in Options class:

```
`
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.options);
        //on toggle switch changes options background and activities buttons background in main layout to plain color
            final Switch optionPlainColored = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            optionPlainColored.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    ImageView background = findViewById(R.id.background);
                    Button attractionsAndArchitecture = findViewById(R.id.attractions_and_architecture);
                    Button barsAndRestaurants = findViewById(R.id.bars_and_restaurants);
                    Button sportAndRecreations = findViewById(R.id.sports_and_recreation);
                    Button nightlifeAndCulture = findViewById(R.id.culture_and_nightlife);
                    //on switch toggle changes background of options activity and 4 buttons in main activity
                    if(optionPlainColored.isChecked()){
                        background.setImageResource(R.drawable.setoptionsbackgroundcolor2);
                        attractionsAndArchitecture.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.attractionsPlainColor));
                        barsAndRestaurants.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.barsPlainColor));
                        sportAndRecreations.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sportsPlainColor));
                       nightlifeAndCulture.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.culturePlainColor));
                    }else{
                        //when unchecked reverses the change
                       background.setImageResource(R.drawable.optionsbackground);
                       attractionsAndArchitecture.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placestovisitbackground));
                       barsAndRestaurants.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barandrestuarantsbackground));
                       sportAndRecreations.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sportandrecreationbackground));
                       nightlifeAndCulture.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nightlifeandculturebackground));

                    }

                }
            });
            //displays toast message about the switch
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toggling the switch will change background color of the Options and Homescreen to plain colored one",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

`

Null object reference on lines where I am changing backgrounds.

XML on MainActivity:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundinfoadditional"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/attractions_and_architecture"
        style="@style/buttonToActivity"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="285dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/placestovisitbackground"
        android:text="@string/attractions_and_architecture"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bars_and_restaurants"
        style="@style/buttonToActivity"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/barandrestuarantsbackground"
        android:text="@string/bars_and_restaurants"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sports_and_recreation"
        style="@style/buttonToActivity"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="284dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sportandrecreationbackground"
        android:text="@string/sports_and_recreation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/culture_and_nightlife"
        style="@style/buttonToActivity"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="282dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nightlifeandculturebackground"
        android:text="@string/culture_and_nightlife"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/options"
        style="@style/options"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.024"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info"
        style="@style/info"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.952"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:text="@string/moscow_concise_guide"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

'

Answer (score 0):

use handler to pass message to mainactivity. like

```
if (MainActivity.xhandler != null) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = message;
        msg.obj = data1;
        MainActivity.xhandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

In MainActivity define handler.

```
Handler xhandler=new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if (MainActivity.xhandler != null) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = message;
        msg.obj = data1;
        MainActivity.xhandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

When I put this into Options Class it just gives me a bunch of cannot resolve symbol (xhandler, Message, what, obj, data1)

Comment: first define `public static xhandler in MainActivity` and `message` is int code which can you check in mainactivity and not need to data1.

Comment: I've written all code needed. What goes into this part in Options class?
 
if(MainActivity.xhandler != null) {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = message;
            msg.obj = data1;
            MainActivity.xhandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
into "data1" and "message"?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer that worked from other source, posting it here (THIS DOES NOT USE SHARED PREFERENCES):
"I think that an alternative to using a separate Activity for the options, is using a DialogFragment. This would allow to show a floating window in the top of your MainActivity layout, and loading the options layout there, including the Switch.

Following this idea, instead of a new Activity, you’d need to create a DialogFragment for the options.

Then, let’s say you have a button in your Activity and you want to change the color. You can refer to the button like this

getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button)
and that’s it :slight_smile:

This way you can access any view in your Activity, change the background color, assign a different image, or whatever you want, without having to deal with preferences or access a different Activity."

OptionsDialogFragment class:
'

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class OptionsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Here we inflate the layout to use with the options dialog
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options, container, false);

        final Switch optionPlainColored = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

        optionPlainColored.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if(optionPlainColored.isChecked()){
                    // we use getActivity() to refer to the views in the Activity layout.
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.attractions_and_architecture).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.attractionsPlainColor));
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bars_and_restaurants).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.barsPlainColor));
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sports_and_recreation).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sportsPlainColor));
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.culture_and_nightlife).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.culturePlainColor));
                } else {
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.attractions_and_architecture).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundattractionsandarchitecture));
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bars_and_restaurants).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundbarsandrestaurants));
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sports_and_recreation).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundsportsandrecreation));
                    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.culture_and_nightlife).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgroundnightlifeandculture));
                }
            }
        });

        return dialogView;
    }
}'
```

In MainActivity:

```
'        Button options = findViewById(R.id.options);
        options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OptionsDialogFragment dialogFrag = new OptionsDialogFragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                dialogFrag.show(fm, "Options");

            }
        });'
```